# Install SSL certification in Visual Studio Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-blob-storage

I have a solution in my visual studio 2012 which has an azure emulator project, and because of the azure blobs needs to use a certification to encrypt files to upload to the blob...

This specific line return an object NULL (in my local machine)

```
X509Certificate2 sslCert = X509CertificateHelper.SelectICRCert();
```

At production environment it's working properly but in my local environment (visual Studio) is not. I Know that I need to install the ssl certificate in my local machine, but I don't know how.

I need to upload many files from a External Hard Drive to the blobs from Visual Studio in my Local Machine.

Thank you.

Comment: provide the code behind `X509CertificateHelper.SelectICRCert()`

Comment: Just right click on the PFX file in Windows Explorer and select install and follow the steps. This should install the certificate in your computer's local certificate store. After that everything should work well.